# Using link_annotation with :Desc option in Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, annotations, pdf-generation, prawn

I have been struggling to link a text heading with a specific page in the Pdf, similar to the linking of `Table of Contents` in the Pdf file. I have found `link_annotation` method to achieve this however there isn't suffice documentation/examples available to use `link_annotation` method with `:Desc` option.

Any ideas how to use `link_annotation` with `:Desc` option?

Link Annotation Documentation: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/prawn-core/Prawn%2FDocument%2FAnnotations:link_annotation

Comment: Check this https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/tree/master/manual/outline

Comment: @AmitPatel the link you shared is for adding Outline, not for annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linking text to specific page at specific offset, `Destinations`
class provide many helper methods. By using [dest_xyz](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pdf-core/PDF/Core/Destinations#dest_xyz-instance_method), text can be linked to specific page at specific offset.

Here is the working example which links text from 1st page to text at 2nd page at specific offset.

```
require 'Prawn'

margin = 36.0
extra_clickable_margin = 4.0
top_offset = 500.0
@pdf = Prawn::Document.new(margin: margin, page_size: 'A4')

clickable_text = "Clickable Annotation to 2nd page at offset #{top_offset}"
text_width  = @pdf.width_of(clickable_text)
text_height = @pdf.height_of(clickable_text)
cursor      = @pdf.cursor
@pdf.text clickable_text

left   = margin
top    = cursor + margin + extra_clickable_margin
bottom = top - text_height - extra_clickable_margin
right  = left + text_width
src_rect = [left, bottom, right, top]

@pdf = Prawn::Document.new(margin: margin, page_size: 'A4')
@pdf.start_new_page
@pdf.text 'Some Text for 2nd page. ' * 40
dest = @pdf.dest_xyz(0, top_offset, nil, @pdf.state.pages[1])
@pdf.link_annotation(src_rect, Dest: dest)
```